# c++ - lists, pointers, and local variables

Tags: c++, list, local

It should be a simple question, but for the life of me I can't finda solution online.

Simply put, creating an object and adding it to a list of pointers doesn't work for me - as soon as I try access the item in the list in a different method to where it was created, it gives an access violation.

So two questions:

1: What's the best way of doing this?

2: Subsequently, if it's not using pointer lists, what's the best way of removing from the list?

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    std::list<testClass*> list;
    addClass(list);
    std::cout << list.front()->a; //item added to list now longer accessible
}

void addClass(std::list<testClass*> list)
{
    testClass* c = new testClass();
    c->a = 1; c->b = 2;
    list.push_back(c); //item still accessible here
}



class testClass
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Comment: that should be `void addClass(std::list<testClass*>& list)`

Comment: When you're doing something that's too hard for you to understand, you should *make a simpler example* first. For instance, you could try `void addInt(int x) { x += 5; } int main() { int n = 0; addInt(n); }` and notice that this doesn't work. That way, you could have asked a more meaningful question, or even discovered the problem yourself.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this _is_ the simpler example. As it turns out, the larger example (which used a static list rather than passing in the list, and which works with references but not pointers) just seems to have a completely unrelated bug that I can't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your `list` by reference, you are passing by value here and so it is making a copy of the container and working on that copy:

```
void addClass(std::list<testClass*> list)
```

If you modify it like so it should work as you want:

```
void addClass(std::list<testClass*> &list)
```

Comment: Damnit, that works. Which sucks, because the actual problem I made that for was that it wasn't working with a _static_ list, rather than a list I passed in. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A first macroscopic error is that `addClass` shold take a `std::list<testClass*> &` so that it operates on the list contained in main, an not on a local copy.

After that, the entire design has to be better focalized:

- Since `testClass` is not polymorphic (there is nothing virtual in it) what is the point to allocate them dynamically? It will probably be easier to let them contained as value directly in the list itself, havig a `std::list<testClass>`.
- Or ... if you need dynamic allocation, you also have to consider **deallocation**, or you wil leak memory: if the list cotains pointers, it will destroy the pointer, not what they point-to.

So now, let's follow the two tracks:

### Treating objects as values

You need a way to construct a `testClass` object from given values.

```
class testClass
{
public:
    testClass(int a_, int b_) 
       :a(a_), b(b_)
    {}

    int a;
    int b;
};
```

and now you can

```
void addClass(std::list<testClass>& list)
{
    list.emplace_back(1,2);
}
```

and

```
int main()
{
    std::list<testClass> list;
    addClass(list);
    std::cout << list.front().a; 
}
```

Note how some `*` disappered!

### Treating objects dinamically

Ok creating with new, but you have to take care of deletion.

One way is delete the pointed from list: just before the `}` in `main`...

```
for(auto p : list) delete p;
```

this will run across the list and call delete for each of the pointers, thus deallocating (and destroying) the object you allocated with new.

**NOTE:**  This does not make the list empty: the list still contains the pointers, they simply point to invalid address. The pointers will be deallocated by the list at the exit from `main`

Another way is not to use plain pointers but smart pointer that delete themselves the content when they are destroyed.

This requires an `std::list<std::unique_ptr<testClass> >` as a container, so that you can

```
void addClass(std::list<std::unique_ptr<testClass> >& list)
{
    list.emplace_back(new testClass(1,2)); 
}
```

Now, when `main` exits, the list gets destroyed with its own elements (the smart pointer) tha in turn will `delete` the `new` allocated objects.